# Note down loading(opening/closing) and searching time of page in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have written a **selenium** code for my project. Pages are  opening and closing but i need to display **Loading(opening/closing)time of page** and also need to note down the **searching time for records** in selenium. THe code is written in **JAVA**
Can anyone advise me which concept/methods I can use here

Comment: what do you mean by "Pages are automatically opening and closing" and "searching time for records" ? please can you clarify more?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas means how much time a page is taking to load and if System is doing query for search of record then Script should return a searching time(Scenario : after entering one record in text field and click on search Button script should return how much time it took to search particular record )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st question to know the opening & closing time you can use below approach.

Before you open any page in selenium include the below command which will store the current *start time* into *start* variable of type *long*.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

After you store the current time of system open the webpage for which you are trying to calculate opening and closing time.

```
driver.get("Some url");
```

After you finish all the intended operations on the web page, use below command which will again store the current system time in *long* type of variable named as *finish*.

```
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Once you get the start and end time for your operation you can easily get the total time in below manner.

```
long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);
```

Also for the searching operation i am not sure what approach you implemented in you code but you can get the searching time in the same manner.

Comment: Same answer is already mentioned by me before you.

Comment: @Rupesh Shinde:  thanks for your answer.. it's working now for both the approach

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to find out how much time does it take to load a page completely using selenium webdriver 2.

Normally web driver should return control to your code only after the page has loaded completely.

So this code may help you to find the time for a page load -

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.get("Some url");

long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);
```

If this does not work then you will have to wait till some element is displayed on the page -

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.get("Some url");

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("ID of some element on the page which will load"));
long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = finish - start; 
System.out.println("Total Time for page load - "+totalTime);
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks sir for Answer. this one is working

Comment: : I already Accepted sir